# LDAP to change user password

Tags: ldap, change-password

As I know, in PHP, we need to connect LDAP over SSL in order to change the user password.

Is there another way, E.G, other languages (JAVA / ASP) to change the LDAP password without SSL required?

**Updates:**

I get `Warning: ldap_mod_replace() [function.ldap-mod-replace]: Modify: Insufficient access"` when I try to modify my account password.

If I try to change other user passwords, I get no error message, but the password still sticks to the old one.

Comment: That would probably depend on the LDAP service you're using.

Answer (score 6):

Many LDAP implementations do indeed require SSL or TLS in order to change/set passwords.  This is a requirement set by the LDAP server, not the language used to access it.  Changing languages will not permit you to override this particular server requirement.

I understand that there are extenuating circumstances where you may not be able to establish a SSL/TLS connection, but in general, you absolutely want to be encrypting password functions like this - even if the server doesn't require it.

**Edit:**  I bet the answer can be founds in the slapd logs.  Also worth reviewing the ACLs: [OpenLDAP Software 2.4 Administrator's Guide, Section 8. Access Control](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html).

Comment: I knew a software which allow user to reset/change password although there is no SSL enabled for my current LDAP.
http://www.manageengine.com/products/self-service-password/index.html

Comment: @neobie maybe I misunderstood your question.  It sounded like you were trying to bypass a ssl requirement dictated by your ldap server.  I'm glad you got it working!

Comment: no it didn't. That is 3rd party software but now I am trying to develop using PHP.

Answer (score 4):

The directory stores password values in the userPassword attribute of the user
entry. Depending on the access control settings for the server, users may set the
value of userPassword in accordance with the password policy you specify, using
standard tools, such as ldapmodify for example.

```
ldapmodify -h host -p port -D "cn=Directory Manager" -w password
dn: uid=bjensen,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
replace: userPassword
userPassword: ChAnGeMe
```

Answer (score 3):

There is the `ldappasswd` utility. e.g.

```
ldappasswd -H ldap://ldap.example.com:389 -D "uid=account-name,ou=serviceaccounts,dc=example,dc=com" -S -W -ZZ
```

If `referral` is returned, then you need to try that server instead. Usually when there is one master server and multiple read-only servers.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using OpenLDAP or Active Directory? Both of them needs a secure connection to let you change your password.

You can't change your Active Directory password with PHP using ldap_mod_replace, you must use ldap_modify_batch if you are not an administrator.

Take a look: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248.aspx

If you use replace (you doesn't send your old password) only administrators can change passwords. But if you use a batch with a delete (with your old password) and an add (with new one), then a user could change his/her own password: http://php.net/ldap-modify-batch

Comment: Also note that the two operations are different: performing `ldap_mod_replace` (or `ldap_modify_batch` with `LDAP_MODIFY_BATCH_REPLACE`) leads to a *password reset* operation, while using `ldap_modify_batch` with a `..._REMOVE` and an `..._ADD` is a *password change* operation. The major difference is that a *reset* operation makes it impossible to access previously encrypted files (because they are encrypted with the old password), while a *change* operation doesn't suffer from this limitation (because the files are decrypted with the old and re-encrypted with the new password).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do this in PHP, without an SSL / TLS connection using PHPs `COM` extension (however using `COM` means you're **required** to use a Windows OS for your application).

Using `COM` also by-passes your AD server's password policy complexity requirements (not sure why).

```
$dn = 'cn=John Doe,dc=acme,dc=org';

$ldap = new COM('LDAP:');

$user = $ldap->OpenDSObject('LDAP://ACME-DC01.corp.acme.org/'.$dn, 'admin-username', 'admin-password', 1);

$user->SetPassword('NewPassword');

$user->SetInfo(); // Saved
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing a User’s Password Using the RootDN Bind

```
ldappasswd -H ldap://server_domain_or_IP -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -W -S "uid=bob,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com"
```